# Angular unit test - Error: <toHaveBeenCalled> : Expected a spy, but got Function

Tags: angular, unit-testing

Hello i'm trying to write 2 unit tests. For the second one i tried with the code below but i got the following error
**Error:  : Expected a spy, but got Function.**

I found solutions to spy on method which is written inside my component but i can't find how to test this setTitle() method!Any ideas?

**My FirstComponent**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-mission',
  template: '<p>{{caption}}</p>'
})
export class FirstComponent implements OnInit {

caption: string;

constructor(private title: Title) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.title.setTitle('Mission accomplished');
 }
}
```

**spec file**

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { FirstComponent} from './mission.component';

describe('FirstComponent', () => {
  let component: FirstComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<FirstComponent>;
  let title: Title;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
     declarations: [ FirstComponent]
   });
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FirstComponent);
component = fixture.componentInstance;
fixture.detectChanges();
}));

it('should create', () => {
  expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});

it('should set the caption property', () => {
});

it('should call the setTitle method', () => {
  title = TestBed.inject(Title);
  expect(title.setTitle).toHaveBeenCalled();
});

});
```

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5xrvem?file=src/app/first/first.component.spec.ts)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `spyOn`

Like this:

Also, you must provide for your dependencies. Using `TestBed.inject` is not enough.

For example change your beforeEach to:

```
  let titleSpyService : jasmine.SpyObj<Title>;
  beforeEach(() => {
    const titleSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('Title', ['setTitle']);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
     declarations: [ FirstComponent],
     providers: [
       { provide: Title, useValue: titleSpy }
    ] 
   });
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FirstComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
  titleSpyService = TestBed.inject(Title) as jasmine.SpyObj<Title>;
 });
```

Comment: I tried but i can't find setTitle method! I test with other methods like ngOnInit which implementation is on this component and it's working. How can i access this method setTitle whick belong to the Title class?

Comment: Still the same, can't find this method! I created a stackblitz, if this make it easier to help https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5xrvem?file=src/app/first/first.component.spec.ts

Comment: Change title = TestBed.inject(Title); to title = TestBed.get(Title);

Comment: get is deprecated: from v9.0.0 use TestBed.inject is the same